# Deleting a file that contain a word in their name. C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to delete any files that contain one word in their name ?
For example: chrome.1323.pf I want to remove any file that contain chrome in their name.
I tried this:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x75)) {

            std::string command = "del /Q ";
            std::string path = "C:\\Windows\\Prefetch\\AUDIOZ.*.pf";
            system(command.append(path).c_str());
        }
```

but it didn't really worked well..

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work well"? Also, try the functionality [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

You can provide [Wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) in filenames which you want to remove:

```c
std::string command = "del /Q C:\\temp\\chrome*";
system(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

Which standard of C++ do you use? Do you have a possibility to use `std::filesystem` or `boost::filesystem`?

Your approach is a Windows only. I would use next algorithm to do resolve your problem:

1. Get list of all files in required directory (recursively if needed) - https://gist.github.com/vivithemage/9517678
2. Process the list of those files and filter out the files which do not have needed extension or substring
3. Delete files which are still in your files list - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove